# Shortcut to resize terminal window

Tags: vim, terminal

I'm trying to create a shortcut to do something like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>pv :wincmd v<bar> :Ex <bar> :vertical resize 30<CR>
```

But instead of having the file explorer on the left, I want to open a new terminal in the bottom and resize it to `30`. I was trying with something like this, but I'm no sure what's wrong:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :terminal<Bar> <C-\><C-n><Bar> :resize 30<CR>
```

Comment: `:terminal` can't be chained with other vim commands because it expects an optional shell command, you have to wrap it into `:execute`, something like `nnoremap <leader>t :exe "terminal"<Bar>resize 30<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

The `botright` command can be used to open the terminal on the bottom of the tab. The `terminal` command with its `++rows` argument can be used to open a terminal with the specified number of rows.

```
nnoremap <leader>t :botright terminal ++rows=30<cr>
```